# How do change a javafx scene with-out the resizing and jumping?

Tags: java, javafx, transition

I have a javafx program that I like many other javafx programs and going from one scene to another. I don't want to open a new window so I want all scenes to share the same same windows just change the content in the windows. This all works fine except the fact that whenever I go from one scene to another there is a brief moment of resize when you notice that the screen is changing. My question is: Is there any way to stop this moment of resize from happening and make it just a smooth transition? Am I not changing the scenes the right way?

Here is an example of how I am changing scenes:

```
/**
     *
     * @param event
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @FXML
    private void loadSelectRuns(ActionEvent event) throws IOException, SQLException {
        Stage stage = getStageFromActionEvent(event);

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SelectRun.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);

        stage.setFullScreen(true);

        stage.setFullScreenExitKeyCombination(KeyCombination.NO_MATCH);
    }
```

This button is triggered from a button on my home menu. I get the current open stage from the action event and set the scene from a loaded FXML file, Lastly I set it to full screen

Comment: Damn, not a duplicate...

Comment: This did solve my problem. I guess you don't know unless you ask